# JavaScript and DOM bindings

Tags: javascript, dom

I am reading the DOM standard where [it states](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/ecma-script-binding.html):

> DOMImplementationRegistry is a global variable which has the following
>   functions: getDOMImplementation(features) ...etc

I am trying to understand but can't find information about:

- who provides the implementation of this `DOMImplementationRegistry`
  object?
- how does JavaScript get the desired DOM implementation? Is it
  implemented in JavaScript (for using in JavaScript)?
- how can I access
  this variable (`DOMImplementationRegistry`)?

Could you explain it to me or provide a useful link please?

Comment: Where were you reading this?

Comment: What are you hoping to do with this? Most of the time, in order to make real web pages that do real things, all you need to know is the standard API for accessing and manipulating DOM elements.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Here is: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/
Appendix H

Comment: @PlatinumAzure I want understand how it works from inside.

Comment: @maximus As far as I can tell, this doesn't seem to be available in Chrome's JS/DOM implementation. You're stuck with whatever `document.implementation` gives you. (There's really not much call for alternative DOM parsers in a browser anyway. Not like there's *that* much call for pluggable XML parser implementations anywhere.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.implementation

Comment: @Jack A `DOMImplementation` isn't the same as a `DOMImplementationRegistry`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the specifications says, it is a global variable. As far as i can see, it is not implemented in Chrome nor in Firefox, otherwise you would be able to use it from the Chrome or Firefox console as, for example, the `DOMImplementation` object (you can find this object as a global variable in the browser's consoles).

This page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMImplementationRegistry states that this feature is not implemented in firefox. I didn't find similar statements pertaining Chrome.

- your question: who provides the implementation of this DOMImplementationRegistry object?

who is implementing the DOM interface, for example browsers like Chrome or Firefox. You can use their implementation running their web console.

- your question: how does JavaScript get the desired DOM implementation?

it is written in the specification you linked. a javascript statement should call `DOMImplementationRegistry.getDOMImplementation(features)` if the global variable `DOMImplementationRegistry` would be existing

- your question: how can I access this variable (DOMImplementationRegistry)?

if implemented, it should be a global variable

- your question: Is it implemented in JavaScript (for using in JavaScript)?

yes, the interface defined in the specification you included is implemented in javascript in order to be used by javascript code

Comment: Trying to understand you answer, you said that "this feature is not implemented in firefox" about DOMImplementationRegistry . Then you wrote: "...who provides the implementation of this DOMImplementationRegistry object?
who is implementing the DOM interface...browsers like Chrome or Firefox." Could you please explain it?
If Firefox doesn't implement the DOMImplementationRegistry then how and by what means, as stated in the link at your answer we get that variable:
"This is a global variable used to get a single DOMImplementation or DOMImplementationList..."?

Comment: Sorry, probably my answer is confusing because also the question is misleading. You ask: "who provides", the correct question is: "who *should* provide". Indeed, a specification is like a plan, and nobody is forced to follow it, and it is not actually still realized. The browsers decide to adhere to a specification freely, they can implement it fully or partially. Firefox *should* provide that variable, but it actually does not. This is the big problem about web development, the different implementation of specifics

Comment: thanks, now I got it, it is quite complicated and seems to be impossible to answer this questions more precisely. Do you think that the browser's source code analysis would help in understanding of this questions?

Comment: Well, in the browser code you cannot find what is missing. If the implementation of this feature is missing, so probably there is nothing in the browser code that will help you about this feature, but you can ask the developers about it. I think this specific feature has been considered not relevant at the moment